# MySQL Event Scheduler Limit

Tags: mysql, database, web-applications

Hi I was thinking of setting around 40-50 or even more MySQL Event that run on an hourly basis to update a specific column data. Is it gonna cause application failure if i do so ?

The main purpose is to implement an hourly billing system by updating the column data with a fixed rate hourly

Comment: 'to update a specific column data' - who knows but maybe a trigger instead?

Comment: I am sry I couldn't get u.. can u plz elaborate?

Comment: I will if you will. What do you mean by 'to update a specific column data'  and why do you think you need 40-50 events?

Comment: Actually I want to build a hourly billing system kind of like how Amazon charges u for an EC2 instance so i thought of creating a event for each user and charge them accordingly